# object oriented programming in c++

Tags: singleton

how do i make only 1 object creation of any class?

Comment: You want to create one instance of a class?

Comment: to don't create it again. Or do you want to prevent that? ;)

Comment: You could use the singleton pattern, but this pattern is, a) very difficult to get right, b) almost always used unnecessarily. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Codenotguru: your question title is rather generic. You should edit your question and make it more specific.

Comment: Singleton pattern may become evil, there are many points that you should consider, on the surface it is the simplest pattern, but if you dig deeper it is dangerous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's known as the *Singleton* design pattern.  There are many tutorials for it, e.g. one [here](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/C++Singleton.html).

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Singleton Pattern: http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton

EDIT: Updated link from C# to C++